# Is there a way to play multiple files in a single dialog/view with synchronization using libvlc

Tags: mfc, libvlc

I am required to create an MFC dialog which can play 8 video files at a time.The additional requirement being able to play videos in sync.

So far I have created the dialog with one media player to be played and played a little with APIs like setting frame rates.The media player works fine and I am able to call the libVLC APIs.

But I am unable to figure out how to sync videos with date/time and how to run multiple videos in single frameWnd.

Comment: P.S. I have created all the controls dynamically.I have 8 static controls and buttons on my dialog.I will try to call libvlc and try opening media.Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to figure out how to sync videos with date/time

This is not supported by LibVLC.

As for having multiple videos, try creating a mosaic https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Make_a_mosaic/

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will check that out.